# yii2 - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 and table prefix

Tags: pdo, yii2-advanced-app

When i'm write:

```
public static function tableName()
{
  return '{{%сurrencies}}';
}
```

I have error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{%сurrencies}}' at line 1
>   The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {{%сurrencies}}

When i'm write:

```
return 'currencies';
```

All is fine. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add any table prefix just add {tableName}.

By setting this property, any token like '{{tableName}}' will be replaced by 'prefixTableName'.

Here is the Documentation for table prefix 
(http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#tablePrefix-detail)

You can set your table prefix in config file as below:

```
'db'=>array(
  'connectionString' => 'xxxxx',
  'username' => 'xxxxx',
  'password' => 'xxxxx',
  'tablePrefix' => 'tbl_', // Table Prefix Here
),
```

Also can you please eloborate What exactly you want to do, So that I can be more specific in terms of my answer.